# ExtJS 6.0 I can't UPDATE single FIELD in my tables

Tags: extjs, webapi

My Store ExtJS 6.0 I can't UPDATE single FIELD in my tables.

```
Ext.define('Movie.store.RentalStatusStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.status',
    storeId: 'status',
    requires: [
        'Movie.model.RentalModel'
    ],
    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        var type = Ext.util.Cookies.get("type");
        if(type==1){
           var id = 0;
        }else{
           var id = Ext.util.Cookies.get("id");
        }
        cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            autoLoad: true,
            model: 'Movie.model.RentalStatusModel',
            remoteSort: true,
            pageSize: 5,
            proxy: {
              type: 'rest',
              enablePaging: true,
              api: {
                create: 'https://localhost:44369/Movies/Addstatus',
                read: 'https://localhost:44369/Movies/Getstatus/'+id,
                update: 'https://localhost:44369/Movies/Editstatus',
                destroy: 'https://localhost:44369/Movies/Deletestatus'
              },
              reader: {
                type: 'json',
                totalProperty: 'TotalCount',
                headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' }
              },
              writer: {
                type: 'json',
              }
            }
        }, cfg)]);
    }
});
```

My Controller to edit Status

```
var ref="123";
      var store1 = Ext.create('Movie.store.RentalStatusStore', {});
    store1.load({
       scope: this,
          callback: function (records, operation, success) {
             var record1 = store1.findRecord('refs', ref);
               console.log(record1)
                record1.set('Transaction_status', text);
                 store1.sync();
             }
           })
```

my web api

```
 `       [Route("Movies/Editstatus/{movie}")]
        [EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
        [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("Delete", "Post", "Get", "Put")]
        [System.Web.Http.HttpPut]
        public IHttpActionResult EditMovie(Movie_transaction movie)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            using (var ctx = new MyEntity())
            {
                var existmovie = ctx.Movie_transaction.Where(s => s.Trans_id== movie.Trans_id).FirstOrDefault();
         
                {
                        existmovie.Transaction_status= movie.Transaction_status;
                        ctx.SaveChanges();
                }
             
            }
            return Ok(movie);
        }
`
```

I tried many times but it gets an errors..

`{"$id":"1","Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Non-static method requires a target.","ExceptionType":"System.Reflection.TargetException","`

I don't know how to fix this...

Here's the body errors:

> {"$id":"1","Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","ExceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException","StackTrace":"   at MovieRentals.Controllers.MoviesController.EditMovie(Movie_transaction movie) in C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\MovieRentals\MovieRentals\Controllers\MoviesController.cs:line 381\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass6_2.b__2(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext()"}

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems not to be in your ExtJs. The error happens in your API. Have you checked if your "movie.Transaction_status" is set?